# Ajax pattern to update javascript chart data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, design-patterns

I'm using [Highchart](http://www.highcharts.com/) API to display charts. There are many chart type to display and the idea is let the user choose a chart from a dropdown, make an ajax request and partially update the chart. The good is i can output a custom response, with custom chart options, layout and data.

The problem here is that chart layout and data are inside the `script` tag in `head`. An empty `div` is then populated by the API.

Which pattern should i use to partially update the chart? Sorry for the very noob question, but i'm feeling a bit confused when dealing with something different from updating `div` with plain text/html as server response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer myself: make `chart` a global javascript variable, initialize charts options (not necessary) send an ajax request and return a JSON object that represent the entire chart object, overriding `chart` global. No need to call `redraw`. **Limitations**: as you can't serialize function you can't dynamically override formatters function (e.g. for tooltips).

If you just want to update data call `addSeries`, `setSize`, `setTitle` (and others) methods.

All explained very well [here](http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/how-to-use) (section 4) and [here](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#chart-object).

Answer (score 0):

i was working a little with hightchart, and what i was doing to change the type of chart is calling a function that go's to a php ajax source and create the chart with a table's db result.

each chart's need a diferente table layout, i think.

and that's why i create separeted files for this.

like:

```
piechart.ajax.php
```

and a div get the return of ajax call and after that, i call the Highcharts to display the div's result's into a chart.

dont know if this will help you, but may be clear your 'mind'

edit:

**html:**

```
<div id="grafic"></div>
```

**js:**

```
    $.post("ajax/piechart.ajax.php", 
            { 
                cache: false,
            }, 
            function(data){ 

                $("#grafic").html(data);

                var table = document.getElementById('datatable'),
                    options = {
                        chart: {
                            renderTo: 'grafic',
                            zoomType: 'xy',
                            defaultSeriesType: 'pie'
                        }
                    };
                    Highcharts.visualize(table, options);
            }
    )
```

Comment: What's the output of `piechart.ajax.php` and what do you mean for "display the div's result's into a chart"? The div is just an empty element filled by Highcharts...

Comment: i extract the result from a table, the source of piechart.ajax.php is a html table, and the return of ajax ( data ) i drop into a div, like $("#div").html(data); and i use the source of #div to create the chart.

Comment: Ok, it seems you're fetching data from an html table, but i'm using a json object and i don't need to display the data as a table. Any idea then?

Comment: in that case, i suggest u take a look in the documentation, they have alot of info's there. And check this ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210879/reload-chart-data-via-json-with-highcharts ) see if help's you