# how to plot the data value from JSON in Highcharts

Tags: jquery, json, highcharts

I have wrote a jquery as :

```
$(function () {
var data = [
{"series_name":"Actual","period_name":"Q1 / 2013","period_final_value":"17"},
{"series_name":"Actual","period_name":"Q2 / 2013","period_final_value":"15"},
{"series_name":"Actual","period_name":"Q3 / 2013","period_final_value":"13"},

{"series_name":"Alarm","period_name":"Q1 / 2013","period_final_value":"14.103"},
{"series_name":"Alarm","period_name":"Q2 / 2013","period_final_value":"14.404499999999999"},
{"series_name":"Alarm","period_name":"Q3 / 2013","period_final_value":"14.966999999999999"},

{"series_name":"Target","period_name":"Q1 / 2013","period_final_value":"15.67"},
{"series_name":"Target","period_name":"Q2 / 2013","period_final_value":"16.005"},
{"series_name":"Target","period_name":"Q3 / 2013","period_final_value":"16.63"}
];
var seriesData = [];
var xCategories = [];
var i, cat;
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
     cat = '' + data[i].period_name;
     if(xCategories.indexOf(cat) === -1){
        xCategories[xCategories.length] = cat;
     }
}
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    if(seriesData){
      var currSeries = seriesData.filter(function(seriesObject){ return seriesObject.name == data[i].series_name;});
      if(currSeries.length === 0){
          seriesData[seriesData.length] = currSeries = {name: data[i].series_name, data: []};
      } else {
          currSeries = currSeries[0];
      }
      var index = currSeries.data.length;
      currSeries.data[index] = data[i].period_final_value;
    } else {
       seriesData[0] = {name: data[i].series_name, data: [data[i].period_final_value]}
    }
}
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Stacked column chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: xCategories
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 30,
            title: {
                text: 'Total fruit consumption'
            },
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: false,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -100,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 20,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColorSolid) || 'white',
            borderColor: '#CCC',
            borderWidth: 1,
            shadow: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br/>'+
                    this.series.name +': '+ this.y +'<br/>'+
                    'Total: '+ this.point.stackTotal;
            }
        },

        series: seriesData
    });
});
```

});

the code above also consists of the JSON data format.
but the values are not showing up.
the code plots X axis with Q1 Q2 and Q3 and the Y axis, also the Series are displayed in the Legend
but the code does't have any columns on screen.
any help appreciated.
Thank You.

Comment: Check if you got the seriesData in the correct format for highcharts

Comment: @ManuM 
thanks . it works ...................
check Fiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/PrasadSS/UMeGS/55/

Comment: hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210879/reload-chart-data-via-json-with-highcharts?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You need to use numbers, instead of strings, so each point y value should be parsed by parseFloat() to achieve correct value.

How your seriesData[0] looks like on output?

Comment: Please look at my [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27983248/need-help-in-plotting-a-chart-using-highcharts-in-angularjs)

Comment: Im sorry, im not familar with the moment.js. Dates can be parsed by spliting text and use Date.UTC() or Date.parse().

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am able to convert my date  using `var st = new Date(moment(start_temp).valueOf()).getTime();` under getOperationReportChartSeriesData function. I am even getting some bars but looks like the difference is very low.. in seconds so the bar is almost invisible.. Trying to fix the same now. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks